# Vanilla JavaScript change api endpoint based on <option> value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a currency converter app using the: 'https://exchangeratesapi.io/' API and I am trying to change the endpoint 'base=' depending on the the  that is dynamically created using the data from the API and added to currencyArr[] and is looped through to create each option. The  tag that I would like to control the change og URL has the id "top-select"

E.g if GBP is selected the url should look like "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP".

I've seen similar questions that were based around React, JQuery or AJAX but I am using vanilla JavaScript and I do not know how to use these libraries yet.

```js
let currencyArr = [];
let ratesArr = [];
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
 let api = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=";
 fetch(api)
  .then(response => {
   return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
   for (currency in data.rates) {
    currencyArr.push(currency);
    ratesArr.push(data.rates[currency]);

    // create 'option' element here
    const optionTop = document.createElement("option");
    const optionBottom = document.createElement("option");
    optionTop.textContent = currency;
    optionBottom.textContent = currency;
    document.querySelector("#top-select").appendChild(optionTop);
    document.querySelector("#bottom-select").appendChild(optionBottom);
   }

   document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keyup", convert);
   document
    .querySelector("#bottom-select")
    .addEventListener("change", convert);
   function convert() {
    const input = document.querySelector("#input");
    let bottomSelectValue = document.querySelector("#bottom-select").value;

    for (let i = 0; i < currencyArr.length; i++) {
     if (bottomSelectValue === currencyArr[i]) {
      document.querySelector("#converted").value = parseFloat(
       ratesArr[i] * input.value
      ).toFixed(2);
     }
     if (isNaN(document.querySelector("#converted").value)) {
      document.querySelector("#converted").value =
       "Please Enter A Number";
     }
    }
   }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-weight: thin;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #90d0ff, #008ef7);
 color: white;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 5em;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;

 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.container input {
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 0.5vh solid white;
 font-size: 7em;
 max-width: 100%;
 outline: none;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-weight: thin;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: visible;
}
::placeholder {
 /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
 color: white;
 opacity: 1;
 /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
 /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 color: white;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
 /* Microsoft Edge */
 color: white;
}

.container select {
 background: transparent;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 border: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -webkit-appearance: button;
 outline: none;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
.converted {
 pointer-events: none;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <link
   href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300&display=swap"
   rel="stylesheet"
  />
 </head>

 <body>

 
   <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
   
   <div class="container" id="ctn1">
    <input type="text"  id="input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder ='Enter your number'"/>

    <select id="top-select"> </select>
  

   <div class="container" id="ctn2">
    <input type="text" class="converted" id="converted" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0.00" />
    <select id="bottom-select"> </select>
   </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Codepen link just incase the API doesn't work in the Stack Overflow snippet: https://codepen.io/oliknight/pen/rXaBBZ

Comment: I think you've already got what you need to solve this! If you put a `console.log(bottomSelectValue);` in your `convert` function, you're getting the updated currency when the dropdown changes. Just break out your fetch call into a separate function like `fetchWithBaseCurrency(currency)` that's called when the dropdown changes. Make this separate function generate a URL based on the `currency` variable it's passed, fetch the data, and update the page (like you currently do on the `window.load` event).

Comment: @thmsdnnr the bottomSelectValue controls what the currency will be converted to, but i want to change the options inside <select id="top-select"> so that when the user clicks on a currency, it will convert from that into the currency the bottomSelectValue variable holds. Also i'm not sure i understand what to do with the rest of the answer as i'm somewhat new to JS and this is my first time using API's and fetch. Is there anyway you could break it down more? Sorry haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to set a variable with the coin you want to fetch, and a listener function `onchange` for the selector, so every time you change the selector, the fetch function runs again, but with the base value you want.

Here is the working snippet (I made it smaller so it could fit the page):

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base='
const topSelector = document.getElementById('top-select')
const bottomSelector = document.getElementById('bottom-select')
const converted = document.querySelector('#converted')
const input = document.querySelector('#input')

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  fetchCurrencyList()
  topSelector.addEventListener('change', convert)
  bottomSelector.addEventListener('change', convert)
  input.addEventListener('keyup', convert)
})

function fetchCurrencyList() {
  return fetchJson(baseUrl + topSelector.value).then((data) => {
    data.rates[data.base] = 1
    for (const currency in data.rates) {
      const optionItem = document.createElement('option')
      const optionItem2 = document.createElement('option')
      optionItem.text = currency
      optionItem.value = data.rates[currency]
      optionItem2.text = currency
      optionItem2.value = data.rates[currency]
      topSelector.appendChild(optionItem)
      bottomSelector.appendChild(optionItem2)
    }
    convert()
  })
}

function convert() {
  const bottomSelectValue = bottomSelector.value
  const topSelectValue = topSelector.value

  converted.value = parseFloat(
    topSelectValue * input.value / bottomSelectValue
  ).toFixed(2)

  if (!converted.value || isNaN(converted.value)) {
    converted.value = 'Please Enter A Number'
  }
}

function fetchJson(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
}
```

```css
html {
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-weight: thin;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #90d0ff, #008ef7);
 color: white;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;

 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.container input {
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 0.1vh solid white;
 font-size: 2em;
 max-width: 100%;
 outline: none;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-weight: thin;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: visible;
}
::placeholder {
 /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
 color: white;
 opacity: 1;
 /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
 /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 color: white;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
 /* Microsoft Edge */
 color: white;
}

.container select {
 background: transparent;
 color: white;
  padding: 0px 14px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 30px;
 border: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -webkit-appearance: button;
 outline: none;
 margin-top: 1%;
}
.converted {
 pointer-events: none;
 margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <link
   href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300&display=swap"
   rel="stylesheet"
  />
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="container" id="ctn1">
    <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder ='Enter your number'"/>

    <select id="top-select"> </select>
   <div class="container" id="ctn2">
    <input type="text" class="converted" id="converted" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0.00" />
    <select id="bottom-select"> </select>
   </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: There was other errors on the original code that should be fixed, so I have edited the snippet to work as intended. Using an Object for the rates instead of 2 Arrays are ideal, it's too risky relaying on index numbers.

Comment: This seems to have worked, but when the page first loads up it sets a default base currency of EUR, so when it loads in if the user does not change the base currency using the drop down it will stay at EUR, i'm thinking the easiest way to fix this would be to set EUR as the default option but I am not sure how to do this

Comment: also what’s a coin?

Comment: I have edited the example code, it uses an Object instead of 2 arrays, it's much safer, and will set the proper default currency.
coins = currency, coins usually are used to refer cryptocoins

Comment: This has worked but for some reason EUR has been removed from the drop down, might have something to do with the fact it's the default currency?

Comment: fixed it, in the baseUrl i changed the base from not being set to CAD and that meant EUR was added back into the drop down.

Comment: Checking the API I can see that the base currency is not part of the rates object. Since the code use it to fill the dropdown, a quick fix is to append the base currency to the object like this:
data.rates[data.base] = 1

Comment: Sorry i'm not too sure what you mean, i'm pretty new with JavaScript and this is my first time working with objects and API's sorry

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand it completely..

What I'd do here is add value attribute to the option tag and push it to the currencyArr which I guess changes the endpoint.

```
let currencyArr = [];
let ratesArr = [];
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let api = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=";
    fetch(api)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            for (currency in data.rates) {
                currencyArr.push(currency);
                ratesArr.push(data.rates[currency]);

                // create 'option' element here
                const optionTop = document.createElement("option");
                const optionRight = document.createElement("option");
                optionTop.textContent = currency;
                optionRight.textContent = currency;
                /* Changed code */
                optionRight.value = currency;
                optionTop.value = currency;
                /* End here */
                document.querySelector("#top-select").appendChild(optionTop);
                document.querySelector("#bottom-select").appendChild(optionRight);
            }

            document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keyup", convert);
            document
                .querySelector("#bottom-select")
                .addEventListener("change", convert);

            function convert() {
                const input = document.querySelector("#input");
                let bottomSelectValue = document.querySelector("#bottom-select").value;

                for (let i = 0; i < currencyArr.length; i++) {
                    if (bottomSelectValue === currencyArr[i]) {
                        document.querySelector("#converted").value = parseFloat(
                            ratesArr[i] * input.value
                        ).toFixed(2);
                    }
                    if (isNaN(document.querySelector("#converted").value)) {
                        document.querySelector("#converted").value =
                            "Please Enter A Number";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

That way you can easily know which option tag is clicked and what value to send..

Comment: I added a bit of extra info into the question if that helps at all, the currencyArr array has the different currency names stored in it and is looped through in order to add each currency name as an option